# sockets stuck in CLOSED state

Tags: sockets, tcp, freebsd

We've written a high performance network application on FreeBSD that deals with a large number of TCP connections. A recent version, when used in production, in rare circumstances, causes the system to run out of file descriptors. On inspection of the system in that state it appears that plenty of sockets get stuck in the CLOSED state. My debugging has revealed no obvious case where we don't close() any sockets.

We recently moved to FreeBSD 8.2 and there are plenty of changes that have been made to the application itself.

What causes sockets to end up in the CLOSED state ? What are the best tools to debug an issue like this ?

Comment: CLOSED is good, do you mean CLOSED_WAIT?

Comment: No, its "CLOSED", which is why its confusing. The OS does not seem to be releasing them.

Comment: If they are CLOSED, then you have done your part. The OS will release it eventually. Maybe you just have to increase ulimit -n? (Or throttle connections when you are out of descriptors)

Comment: That's an operating system problem, not your code. The CLOSED state should be extremely transient and unobservable.

Comment: The only reference I found was this - http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-net/2008-June/018544.html - which concluded that the CLOSED state was caused by an application bug.

Comment: And another - https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node/issues/99 -  which is JS, but draws similar conclusions: application bug.